# I'm trying to create csv file with path.join

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to save the part of dataframe to csv file with the following name and parameters:

```
train_file_name = "train/lastfm.train.0"
train_data[["user_id", "artist_id", "total-plays"]].to_csv(
path.join(data_dir, train_file_name),
sep="\t",
header=False,
index=False
)
```

returns the Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/Documents/lastfm/train/lastfm.train.0'
```

But the directory is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directory of train is not made it will create this error, you may ensure the creation of the full directory path by calling this first

**Run this before you call to_csv**

```
directory = path.join(data_dir, "train/lastfm.train.0")
if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
```

*EDIT:* **Another issue will be a file permission issue**.
Change the permission of the folder you are trying to write in

```
sudo chmod 755 train
```

Or on windows right click the folder and uncheck read-only

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it gives: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/Documents'

Comment: As Robert said, you need to change the Permissions of the folder. Please read his second step.